# How to verify teleportation was successful in this circuit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, teleportation

In this circuit ([link](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/new-experiment?initial=N4IgdghgtgpiBcICOEDOUC0AXGAbGGAxgE4BepGAjCADTJpQIgDyACgKIByAigIIDKAWQAEAJgB0ABgDcAHTABLMIVwBXACYxhs5HgUAjSuKWEdcsPKTEYAc2FIA2gGYAuuZK3hEBwFY38jzsScmd-ZWsg4gAPKIcAFjD5AAt7B0owwijU9JpHUTD9CGJiBRhie3MArMdJF1y0sJSagqKSsor5eVg0VWtU2uEMAD5hYNIHWvNu1F6tR3TBkZIYiZbi0vKkSsUAM2EACmWogF5jygBKYWqHfPMFPcOyUlOL4VJU2-lC9fatzrBprMPi5Fl4GtJaCBNKgSAoAA5YBQAezATBAAF8gA)), `q0` is Alice's qubit and `q1`, `q2` are entangled qubits given to Alice and Bob respectively. After measuring `q2` in this circuit, how can it be verified that the state of `q0` and `q2` are the same?

By default, `q0` is in ground state, I assume. So, shouldn't `q2` be also in the ground state if the state was teleported.

[image: teleportation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the circuit construction using classical condition like you have is not executable on IBM hardware at the moment. Devices like Honewywell Trapped ion allows you to do such thing (I think). However, thanks to principle of deferred measurement, we can push the measurement all the way back to the end of the circuit. [See here.](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html#real_qc)

Essentially, your circuit becomes

[image]

---

The state of $q2$ will depends on the state of $q0$. If $q0$ starts in the state $|0\rangle$ then measurement in $q2$ will always (assume no noise) be 0. If instead I add the $X$ operation on $q0$ to turn it into the state $|1\rangle$ then measurement on $q2$ will registered a 1.

For example: if I initialize $q0$ to the state $|0\rangle$ then I will have

[image]

---

but **if I initialize $q0$ to the state $|1\rangle$ then I will have**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a 3 qubit system, you might get results like 000, 010, 011 etc. but the leftmost bit of the readout will always be zero. This is how we know that the teleport has worked.